# Semantic Package: Multiple Lines in Conclusion

Tags: line-breaking

I am using the [`semantic` Package](http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/semantic/semantic.pdf) and I would like to place line breaks in the conclusion part of an inference rule.

For example, I would like to write something like:

```
\inference{A}{B \\ C \\ D}
```

Unfortunately, the package only supports line breaks for the first part (premises) of a rule. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing prevents you from using `array` in the “conclusion” part:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{semantic}

\begin{document}

\inference{A}{\begin{array}{@{}c@{}} B \\ C \\ D \end{array}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, your solution works perfectly. 
If I may ask: what does an expression like "@{} " mean?

Comment: @ftl It removes the padding usually at the left/right of a column